# SecureCRT crashes since upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I've been using Ubuntu 11.04 for a few months now... recently i have upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 and since the upgrade SecureCRT ssh client has not been able to run... it keeps stalling and crashing.

Can anyone help me as to where to start looking for the problem or maybe someone has had a similar one.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](http://binarydelusions.com/2011/10/11/installing-securecrt-on-ubuntu-11-04/) you need to install `libpython2.6`

```
sudo apt-get install libpython2.6
```